# Is "char* string[]" equivalent to "char** string" in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, char

Is `char* string[]` equivalent to `char** string` in C++ ? What are exactly the differences between these two declarations ? What is the best declaration in terms of memory access speed ?

Thanks,

Comment: They are equivalent in that they are both terrible ways to represent a group of strings in c++. In most cases, you'd be much better off with a std::vector<std::string>

Comment: I assume his question relates to `argc`, which is one of the two above signatures

Answer (score 10):

`char * s[]` is an array of pointers. `char ** s` is a pointer to a pointer. Arrays aren't the same as pointers, so the two are different.

(What *is* true is that you can often treat an array as a pointer to its first element, so it's OK to say `s[1][2]` in both cases.)

Note that `char *s[]` isn't actually valid on its own. It's either a declaration:

```
const char * s[] = { "hello", "world" };  // really `const char * s[2]`
```

Or it's a function argument, in which case it *is* actually identical to `char**`:

```
void foo(char * s[]); // same as `void foo(char ** s)`
```

Comment: It depends on the context. If they're parameters to a function, then yes they are the same.

Comment: @KerrekSB what about s = malloc(sizeof(char) * LEN);

Comment: @oussama: What about it? That allows you to treat `s` as a (simple) pointer to char, and you can dereference `s + 0` up to but excluding `s + LEN`.

Comment: @oussama: if `s` is `const char*[]`, then I don't think assigning that to it would be meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

`char* string[]` can decay to `char** string` e.g. when passed as a parameter *by value* or returned from function *by value*

The two are not identical

Answer (score 0):

They are different, however, arrays in most cases decay to pointers (when being passed by value as a parameter to a function, for example).  So it's perfectly fine to slap an index on there in such cases and call it a day.